# How do I solve $0= \frac{d}{dx}(x^2u'(x))$ in $C^1[-2,1]$ with boundary conditions

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I am trying  to solve the following ODE with boundary conditions in the set $C^1[-2,1]$, with $u(-2)=-1/2$ and $u(1)=1$. that is I must tell if there exist a solution $u$ in $C^1[-2,1]$

$$0= \frac{d}{dx}(x^2u'(x))\\ 
x^2u'(x)=c$$

I think I can't just put $x^2 $to the right in the denominator  and  and integrate  because $0$ is in the domain, how does one proceed in this cases? And when is that the solution is admissible?

Comment: You find $u=-\frac{c_1}x+d_1$ on $[-2,0)$ and $=-\frac{c_2}x+d_2$ on $(0,1]$ and for $u$ to be defined at $0$ and continuous, $c_1=c_2=0$ and $d_1=d_2,$ so the answer is no (because $-1/2\ne1$).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry I fixed that, I meant the derivative of u

Answer (score 2):

Assume that such $u$ exists. As you wrote, $\frac d{dx}(x^2u'(x)) = 0$ implies $x^2u'(x) = c$, for all $x\in[-2,1]$. Plugging in $x=0$ gives us $c = 0$, so we have $x^2u'(x) = 0$ for all $x\in [-2,1]$, so $u'(x) = 0$ for all $x\neq 0$, but due to continuity, $u'(x) = 0$ for all $x\in [-2,1]$. Thus, $u(x)$ is constant function. However, $u(-2)\neq u(1)$. Contradiction.